# Image Swap on MouseOut (JavaScript, not JQ)

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create functions to mouseover and mouseout of images.  The tricky part is this function needs to work for any image, and I cannot use direct image names.  I have to therefore use variables.

The HTML code is as follows for the images:

The HTML for the images is like this, and there are 3 images:

```
<img src="images/h1.jpg" alt="" id="images/h4.jpg" onmouseover="swapToNewImage(this)" onmouseout="swapImageBack(this)">
```

I'm expecting that you have to reference the id for the new image, and then the src attribute for the previous image to revert when you mouseout.

The problem is that, if I reference the id attribute, the image no longer has information on the src attribute so I cannot call it to revert back.

Here is the JavaScript I have thus far.  It works to swap the image to a new one, but not to swap it back :(

```
//FUNCTION 
var $ = function (id) { 
    return document.getElementById(id); 
}           

//ONLOAD EVENT HANDLER      
window.onload = function () {

  //GET ALL IMG TAGS
  var ulTree = $("image_rollovers");
  var imgElements = ulTree.getElementsByTagName("img");
  //PROCESS EACH IMAGE
  //1. GET IMG TAG
  for (var i = 0; i < imgElements.length; i++) {
    console.log (imgElements[i]);
    console.log (imgElements[i].getAttribute("src"));
    //2. PRELOAD IMAGE FROM IMG TAG
    var image = new Image();
    image.setAttribute("src", imgElements[i].getAttribute("src"));
    //3. Mouseover and Mouseout Functions Called    
    image.addEventListener("mouseover", swapToNewImage);
    image.addEventListener("mouseout", swapImageBack);
  } 
}

//MOUSE EVENT FUNCTIONS
var swapToNewImage = function(img) {
  var secondImage = img.getAttribute("id", "src");
  img.src = secondImage;
}

var swapImageBack = function(img) {
  var previousImage = img.getAttribute("src");
  img.src = previousImage;  
}
```

Let me know if you can help me figure out how to call the image's src attribute so it can be reverted back.  Again, I cannot reference specific image names, because that would be a lot easier (:  Thank you!

Comment: Please improve your indentation!

Answer (score 0):

Well, You can use a data attribute to store your src, and a data attribute to store the image you want to swap when mouseover.

Please try the following example.

```js
var swapToNewImage = function(img) {
  var secondImage = img.dataset.swapSrc
  img.src = secondImage;
}

var swapImageBack = function(img) {
  var previousImage = img.dataset.src
  img.src = previousImage;  
}
```

```html
<img src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259803/pexels-photo-259803.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" alt="" data-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/259803/pexels-photo-259803.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500" data-swap-src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/416160/pexels-photo-416160.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500"  onmouseover="swapToNewImage(this)" onmouseout="swapImageBack(this)">
```

I also notice that the image tag is generated by code, in order to set the dataset values, we can do this:

```
  var image = new Image();
  image.scr = [src]
  image.dataset.src = [src]
  image.dataset.swapSrc = [swap src]
```